# Django - passing an attribute value to as_view in TemplateView

Tags: python, django, django-templates

This is my view (simplified):

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'bar'
        super(MyView, self).__init__()
```

This is in urls.py:

```
url(
    r'^/foo/$',
    MyView.as_view(foo='baz'), name='my_view'
)
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: MyView() received an invalid keyword 'foo'. as_view only accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class.
```

**Why?** I thought this would work. :/

At least according to this post:
http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2011/08/24/class-based-views-walkthrough.html#class-view

If I understood this correctly, this should have set the attribute `foo` to the value `'baz'` passed in `as_view`. Without any attributes in `as_view`, the value should be `'bar'`, as defined in `__init__`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're explicitly setting a value on an instance of the class in `__init__()`. However, the class itself still doesn't have an attribute `foo`, as it is unaware of dynamic attributes on instances: `hasattr(MyView, 'foo')` always returns `False`.

This would work as you expected your code to work:

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    foo = 'bar'

url(
    r'^/foo/$',
    MyView.as_view(foo='baz'), name='my_view'
)
```

Comment: Will this change this value only for this instance of the view or for the class itself? What happens if I have another URL binding without a parameter in urls.py and it's called after this one from the question? Will the value inside be `'bar'` or `'baz'`?

Comment: @morgoth84 The `MyView` class will be instantiated with the keyword arguments passed to the `as_view` method. It will not change any attribute on the class itself. If another url binding does not pass another value for `foo`, the value on the `MyView` instance will be the default `'bar'`.

Comment: @morgoth84 One more thing, you can override `__init__` on `View` subclasses, but you have to capture all keyword arguments (`__init__(self, **kwargs)`) and pass them to a call to `super`, or you will break stuff.

Answer (score 3):

The source code of Django `View` class has this though:

```
if not hasattr(cls, key):
    raise TypeError
```

So it is not enough to create the attr on an instance in `__init__` ...it has to exist on the class itself:

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    foo = 'bar'
```

Comment: Django's default implementation of `__init__` on `View` will handle all keyword arguments and set them on the instance. Your implementation of `__init__` will actually break things if you try to pass another keyword argument.